# Algebraic approach to prove the mixing property of Lorenz flow on hyperbolic surface

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-dynamics

We knew that the noncompact subgroups of SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$) are mixing by Howe-Moore ergodicity theorem. I am curious about Lorenz flow, if we have a algebraic approach to prove the mixing property of Lorenz flow under some conditions? Please give me ideas or some references for that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Mixing wrt to which measure? Also the action you've mentioned is not mixing wrt to any measure, say the horocyclic flow along a compact period is not mixing (it is Kronecker or in more generality some nilflow). Same thing happens with the geodesic flow along a period.

The proof of the mixing you've mentioned with the HM theorem is pretty special, and needs the usage of representation theory (i.e. it will not work plainely for geodesic flow along variable curvature manifold). The most basic proof of mixing is probably some variant of the ergodicity argument of Hopf.